# navigation based template with out using xib file

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

hii every one

can i use a navigation based template to create project in which screens will be designed programaticaly (with out using interface builder)

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to programmatically create a navigation interface.

There are many references to getting this done. I have done it many times too. I assure you that the following link describes exactly this.

You might find it helpful to follow the useful steps on there.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Go to create a navigation controller on the left side of the pane, you dont want to click the first two sub links because they talk about it with xib files, you want the third link where it does exactly what you want **Creating a Navigation Interface Programmatically**

let me know if that helps

**PK**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
The mainView xib file has an empty canvas, it's has however an NavigationController which can be used in your code. The rootViewController could be replaced by just programmatically building up your view.